# Laravel Twilio integration "resolvable from the IoC container"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, inversion-of-control, twilio, ioc-container

I want to use twilio API in laravel 4 and i have used https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio package and read the all the steps but i didn't get this point "And make these objects resolvable from the IoC container".

So please tell me how to make object using IoC container for twilio.

Thanks in advance.

[Instructions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxK8Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am adding an answer to this old question because it came up as I was trying to Google the exact same issue OP was having when this question was asked.

I was also confused by the wording in the instructions for that library. The [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container#binding) point out:

> Almost all of your service container bindings will be registered within service providers...

Assuming this is how the Twilio library is built, if you look a few lines above the on you are quoting, it instructs the developer to "add a new item to the providers array". The two sections beneath that (one starting with "This will..." and the other starting with "And make...") are both explaining the benefits of adding that service provider.

In conclusion, all you should need to do is add that service provider to your app.php file, per the instructions on the GitHub page.